# Android - Firebase Console - SHA1 can't be added - previous owner removed - original project is orphaned

Tags: android, firebase, console, sha1, signature

Our app is currently published and productive on Google PlayStore.

We want now to integrate our app with Firebase, but when I try to add the SHA1 as signature into Firebase Console, we obtain the following known error:

[image]

We followed all the [suggested instructions](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0), but sadly we don't own the Firebase Project containing this signature.
We didn't know which Firebase project is the one that has this signature attached, so I contacted Firebase Support.

They answered this:

> Hi,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. To give you an insight on why you're encountering this error, the
> same package name and SHA-1 pair could only be used once across Google Cloud and Firebase projects. Checking our records, it seems that the previous owner of the project has been removed and the project became an orphaned project. Note that orphaned projects' resources are inaccessible. You can read more from [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines).
>
> Since the only way to delete the conflicting OAuth client ID is to contact the owner of the
> project to have them delete it and the project where this client ID exists no longer has an owner, it will be impossible to manually delete the OAuth client ID.
>
> As much as we'd like to help, unfortunately, **the only workaround available for you at the moment is to either generate a different SHA-1 key or use a different package name**.
>
> If you do have other issues related to Firebase, you could reach out to us through our support channel.
>
> Sincerely,
> Jacque

So, the Firebase guy suggests using a different signature or to change the package name, but AFAIK if I do that there will be impossible to publish the app in the Playstore.

1. Am I right?
2. What else can we do? We do need to integrate the app with Firebase.

Comment: any solutions . we cant loose our playstore app

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your app is unable to use certain Firebase products (most notably, Firebase Authentication, and anything related to that in terms of functionality) if you can't register it with the Firebase console.  If you can't remove the app from the orphaned project, there's nothing you can do to resolve this yourself, except for unpublishing your app from the market and adding it again with a new signature.

You could possibly try to contact the Play store and see if they can make an adjustment for your app, but I doubt they will be able to do that.